# Solr search for distinct "nids" based on keywords

Tags: solr

```
 <fields>
    <field name="mongo_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="nid" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="keywords" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" />
 </fields>
```

I want to get back ALL of the nid's (distinct) that match the keywords.

```
 $solr = new Apache_Solr_Service(SOLR_HOST, SOLR_PORT, SOLR_WEBAPP); 

 //How would I search here?
 $results = $solr->search('search', 0, 100);
```

EDIT:

Does this look right?

```
    $solr = new Apache_Solr_Service(SOLR_HOST, SOLR_PORT, SOLR_WEBAPP);
    $results = $solr->search(Apache_Solr_Service::escapePhrase($_GET['keywords']), 0, 0, array('facet' => 'true', 'facet.field' => 'nid', 'rows' => 0, 'facet.mincount' => 1));

    foreach($results->facet_counts->facet_fields->nid as $nid=>$count)
    {
        $nids[] = (int)$nid;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll want to use faceting. Facet on the `nid`:

```
?q=search&facet=true&facet.field=nid&rows=0
```

It will give you a list of the `nid`s that match along with the number of times each is found in the search. With `&rows=0` only the facet counts will be returned.

**Edit**: One more thing, make sure to set `facet.limit=-1` (or any other negative number) to specify ALL results, and `facet.mincount=1` to make sure that only matches are returned. Otherwise it will return non-matches with counts of zero. If you want to sort by count (it won't by default if `facet.limit` is less than 1) also add `facet.sort=count`.

Comment: I've not used the PHP Solr Service so I couldn't say for certain, but to my untrained eyes it looks OK.